# Compare data from two tables in rails and post in third

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models; User, Project, Skill. I have associated user & skill and skill & project. Now I want to assign a project to users based on skill, if they have the skill needed for the project they can be assigned, otherwise can't. No limit on how many users can work on one project.
I am working on rails. Need a start to the problem.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add a model called ProjectAssignment using user:references and project:references. Once you have that and add your has_many :though to the other two tables, add a condition to a "Add User" form that only allows users that have matching skills for that project.

Answer (score 0):

One method to get a view of available projects/users would be to add has_many :through to each using the skills table....

```
def User < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :skill
  has_many :available_projects, through: :skill, source: :project
end

def Project < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :skill
  has_many :available_users, through: :skill, source: :user
end
```

Then call the associations as needed...

```
user.available_projects
```

and...

```
project.available_users
```